# Mi formulario con HTML y PHP no funciona

Tags: php, html, formularios

Necesito ayuda para hacer funcionar el formulario de mi página web, ya que no llegan los mensajes.

Utilizo un archivo PHP externo (`form.php`) que vinculo a mi archivo HTML.

Podéis ver el formulario en:

- https://www.afsdesign.es/contacto.html

Éste es el código HTML del formulario:

```
    <form class="row inner" id="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="form.php">
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-12">
   <label><span>Nombre</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
 </div>
 <!-- end form-group -->
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-12">
   <label><span>Apellido</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" required>
 </div>
 <!-- end form-group -->
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-12">
   <label><span>Correo</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
 </div>
 <!-- end form-group -->
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-12">
   <label><span>Asunto</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required>
 </div>
 <!-- end form-group -->
 <div class="form-group col-12">
   <label><span>Mensaje</span></label>
   <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
 </div>
 <!-- end form-group -->
 <div class="form-group col-12">
   <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">ENVIAR</button>
 </div>
 <!-- end form-group -->
```

Os dejo el código PHP para ver lo que está fallando:

```php
<?php

    $to = "afsprodesign@gmail.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $headers = "From: $from";
    

    $fields = array();
    $fields{"name"} = "Name";
    $fields{"email"} = "E-mail";
    $fields{"subject"} = "Subject";
    $fields{"message"} = "Message";

    $body = "Here is the message from yourwebsite:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Pues a simple vista  es  que estas intentando ejecutar codigo `php` en un documento `html` . Cambia la extensión del archivo.

Comment: No, utilizo un archivo PHP externo (form.php) que vinculo a mi archivo HTML.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos si la función `mail()` te funciona con correos sencillos? Es posible que tu proveedor de alojamiento tenga inhabilitado el envío a través del MTA local del servidor web. Además, ¿son erratas de copiar y pegar las líneas similares a `$fields{"name"}`? Deberían ser como `$fields["name"]`. Además, tu página envía el formulario a `/php/process.php` (genera un error 404 - no encontrado) y no a `form.php`.

Comment: He cambiado los campos como dices al formato `$fields["name"]` y actualizado el action a `form.php` pero sigue sin funcionar. Mi proveedor de alojamiento me ha dicho lo siguiente: Lamentamos informarle que al no disponer de servicio de programación no sabemos como resolver su caso en su totalidad, pero hemos generado un formulario de prueba en:
https://afsdesign.es/prueba.php  el cual si que envía correos de manera correcta.

Revise el código de dicho formulario y pruebe a configurar los mismos valores en el suyo.

Comment: No has cambiado nada, o lo has cambiado donde no debes, sigue enviándose a `/php/process.php`. Recuerda que estás usando código javascript que inutiliza lo que pongas en el `action` del formulario. Para ser exactos el envío se realiza en el archivo `/js/contact.form.min.js`. Allí tienes el código que genera realmente el envío del formulario (a la URL incorrecta) usando el parámetro `url:"php/process.php"` de `ajaxSubmit()` dentro de la propiedad `submitHandler` del validador de formularios.

Comment: Ya he conseguido que funcione!! El problema estaba en que no tenía ninguna carpeta llamada php, sino que tenia el archivo php en la raíz. Mil gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Y no solo eso, habrás cambiado el nombre del archivo php de `form.php` a `process.php`, ¿verdad?. ¿No hubiera sido más sencillo cambiar el código JavaScript? Además, si no conoces bien cómo funciona SMTP internamente, y/o no realizas un saneado adecuado de los parámetros enviados, deberías evitar hacer uso de la función `mail()`. Si no se toman las medidas adecuadas podría ser muy sencillo inyectar cabeceras SMTP en un formulario para poder usarlo para el envío de correos maliciosos o SPAM. Por este motivo te aconsejo usar `PHPMailer` para realizar el envío de mensajes de correo electrónico.